# Want to go back to a function on if/else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, void

Please look at this code, and I will explain:

```
void GameOver()
{
    cout << "\nWelp, you died. Want to try again?" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == "Yes" || "yes")
    {
        /*This is where I want the code. I want it to go back to the last
        function that the player was on.*/
    }

    if (choice == "No" || "no")
    {
        cout << "Are you sure? The game will start over when you open it back up." << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == "No" || "no")
        {
            cout << "Well, bye now!" << endl;
            usleep(1000000);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I would like it so that when I choose "Yes" in the GameOver function, I want an `if/else` statement that says "if you came from **this function,** then you will go to **that function**", you see what I'm saying?

For example, let's say I am in the `GameOver` function and I came from a `FightProcess` function. I choose "Yes" then it will go to the `Town` function.
How would I code that?

Comment: From `void` do you mean a function which returns void ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a statement like this:

```
if (choice == "Yes" || "yes")
```

Is coded wrong, and will always evaluate as true. You need to use this instead:

```
if (choice == "Yes" || choice == "yes")
```

Or better, use a case-insensitive comparison function, like this:

```
if (strcmpi(choice.c_str(), "Yes") == 0)
```

Second, unless you add an input parameter, or use a global variable, `GameOver()` has no idea who is calling it. So what you want to do does not belong in `GameOver()` itself to begin with. It belongs in the calling function instead. `GameOver()` exits the game if the user chooses not to continue. That is all it should do. The calling function should decide how to retry if the game does not exit. For example:

```
void GameOver()
{
    cout << "\nWelp, you died. Want to try again?" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    //if (choice == "Yes" || choice == "yes")
    if (strcmpi(choice.c_str(), "Yes") == 0)
        return;

    cout << "Are you sure? The game will start over when you open it back up." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    //if (choice == "No" || choice == "no")
    if (strcmpi(choice.c_str(), "No") == 0)
        return;

    cout << "Well, bye now!" << endl;
    usleep(1000000);
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void FightProcess()
{
    ...
    if (defeated)
    {
        GameOver();
        Town();
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Or, if `Town()` is the function that called `FightProcess()`:

```
void FightProcess()
{
    ...
    if (defeated)
    {
        GameOver();
        return;
    }
    ...
}

void Town()
{
    ...
    FightProcess();
    ...
}
```

Or, it might make more sense to have `FightProcess()` loop instead:

```
void FightProcess()
{
    ...
    do
    {
        ...
        if (won)
            break;
        GameOver();
        ...
    }
    while (true);
    ...
}
```

See how things get more flexible when you don't put restrictive logic where it does not belong?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a parameter in the `GameOver` function. Then you could pass a different parameer each time you want to go somewhere else. For example, call `GameOver(1)` from function 1 and `GameOver(2)` from function 2.

This is assuming that returning from `GameOver` and executing different options in the calling function isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can choose to fire a event in FightProcess().

eg:-

```
void FightProcess(){
   ...
   if( ...){
      observer.send("FightProcess"); // or with more information. 
                               //observer.send("FightProcess",Avatar::Killed);
      GameOver();
     }

}
```

And in the GameOver() you can query the observer to find what the last event was.